# Find the range of values of $|PA|+|PB|+|PC|$.

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be vertices of an equilateral triangle and suppose $P$ is an arbitrary point on the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$. I am trying to obtain bounds for the quantity $$|PA|+|PB|+|PC|$$

**Proven already:**

$|PA|^2+|PB|^2+|PC|^2 = 6r^2$, where $r$ is the radius of the circumcircle

**Intuition:**

The minimum occurs when $P$ coincides with any vertex, and the maximum occurs when $P$ is half-way between any two vertices. But how to prove this, if it is even true?

Comment: Applying Ptolemy's theorem in the inscribed quadrilateral PABC, you'll see that, assuming $|PA| \leq |PB| \leq |PC|$, you get that $|PC| = |PA| + |PB|$. So in general $|PA| + |PB| + |PC| = 2\text{max}(|PA|,|PB|,|PC|)$ so it's enough to find the range of the longest of the three segments.

Comment: Another approach for an upper bound would be to use the inequality $3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq (a+b+c)^2$ for any reals $a,b,c$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Schooten%27s_theorem